# Gerrit hooks redirection

Tags: git, redirect, hook, gerrit

Are you using any hooks for gerrit? I need one to scan the patchset.

I tried to create update hooks under `GIT_DIR/hooks/`, but gerrit will bypass that hook when merge, while it works when pushing to git directly.
Then I tried to create `gerrit_site/hooks/patchset_created` with **+x** permission. I can see the error_log like '`echo $GIT_DIR`', but the message cannot redirect to user interface like ssh terminal. Also exit 0 and 1 doesn't block the pushing.

Is it possible for the gerrit hook acts as git one which can redirect message to user and block some patchset?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible for the gerrit hook acts as git one which can redirect message to user and block some patchset?

No.  Gerrit hooks cannot block action and cannot redirect output back to the user.  They run post-action, so the action is already done by the time the hook is called.  See the official documentation at http://gerrit-documentation.googlecode.com/svn/Documentation/2.4.2/config-hooks.html

Adding pre-commit hooks is being worked on currently and will be available in future versions of Gerrit, likely as a plugin.

The best current option is to create a Gerrit hook which scans the patchset like you describe and then comments on the change in Gerrit using the ssh interface.  At $dayjob, we use such a hook to give a -2 review score automatically to patches with commit messages which don't meet our standards.

Comment: Yes, I searched out and finally use the ssh to set review -2. But I think it might have one problem, if my review-2 is removed by someone like admin, then the patchset which I dislike will merge in.

Comment: The only way to remove a score is if the admin went in and manually changed the database.  This would be quite a bit of trouble, so I don't believe it is a big concern.  Also, I don't see why the admin would do such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be undocumented and i haven't tested it yet myself, but the ref-update (without d from ref-updated) hook seems to do what you deserve: https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/#/c/31350/